# access to Message-ID header in Outlook 2010 mail item?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

i want to create Outlook 2010's add-in for send Message-Id Header of selected message to my application, how to access to Message-ID header in Outlook 2010 mail item?

Answer (score 5):

Read the `PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F`) using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty()`.