# How to get Gmail threadid from an Outlook Add-in (when using Google Outlook Sync)?

Tags: c#, outlook, google-api, vsto, gmail-api

I am writing an Outlook Add-in which will be used in conjunction with [Google Apps Sync](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync). My add-in needs the Gmail thread-id, however I don't know how to get this from the add-in code.

I have access to the Outlook MailItem in C#

```
var email = this.OutlookItem as Outlook.MailItem;
```

This contains properties such as body, subject etc and also a ConversationID. But the conversationID is not the Google threadid, it's an internal outlook id.

I've poked around the properties of the `MailItem` object but no success. Anyone know how to find the thread-id from the within the add-in? I am thinking of resorting to doing a gmail api query of the date/time/sender from within the add-in but would rather not have to incur that overhead.

Comment: Take a look at the message with OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) - click IMessage button and look at the available MAPI properties. All MIME headers will be in PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely the Google Sync add-on exposes the thread id as it's not meant to be developed against as far as I know. I'd suggest you look at implementing the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) with your add-on. If you can grab the messages Message-ID SMTP header from Outlook then it should be possible to do a:

```
threads.list(userId='me', q='rfc822msgid:abc123')
```

where abc123 is the actual id. This should give you the Gmail thread id as a result. See the reference guide on [threads.list()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list) for more info.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14477199/1503886 for outlook message I'd retrieval

Comment: Yes, was trying to find out how to get the Message-ID and you beat me to it. Thank you so much for the help, this gives me what I need.